# If $U \subset \mathbb R^n$ is homeomorphic to an open convex set $V \subset \mathbb R^n$, is $U$ regular open?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $V \subset \mathbb R^n$ is an open convex subset and $U \subset \mathbb R^n$ is an open set with $n \ge 3$. If $f: V \to U$ is a homeomorphism and in particular $f$ *cannot* be extended to a homeomorphism to the closure of $\bar{V}$, can we know whether $U$ is regular open or not?

A set $E$ is regular open if $\bar{E}^{\circ} = E$, i.e., it coincides with the interior of its closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot say anything about $U$.

1) Let $V = (0,1)^n$ which is an open cube, in particular is convex and regular. Define $f : V \to V, f(x_1,\dots,x_n) = 
\begin{cases}
(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}, \frac{x_n}{2}) & x_n \le x_{n-1} \\
(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}, \frac{x_{n-1}}{2} + \frac{x_n - \frac{x_{n-1}}{2}}{1 - x_{n-1}}(x_n - x_{n-1}) ) & x_n \ge x_{n-1}
\end{cases}$

This is easily seen to be homeomorphism which does not extend to $\overline{V}$.

2) Let $B_1(0)$ be the open ball around $0$ with radius $1$, $V = \{x = (x_1,\dots,x_n) \in B_1(0) \mid x_2 > 0 \}$ and $U = \{x = (x_1,\dots,x_n) \in B_1(0) \mid x_1 < 0 \text{ or } x_2 \ne 0 \}$. Note that $U$ is not regular. Write $x = (z,x')$ with $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $x' \in \mathbb{R}^{n-2}$ Define a homeomorphism $f : V \to U, f(z,x') = (z^2,x')$. This does not extend to a homeomorphism on $\overline{V}$.